# Xcode 10 svnX issue

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, svnx

After updating to Mojave & Xcode 10. I am facing problem with SVN repository. Even though I know apple has removed svn source control from Xcode 10 still I think using svnX I can manage my codebase. See below the error I am getting -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected now. I have just updated svnX version earlier one was 1.3 and now it is 1.3.4